# How to remove all components from a JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint, removeall

I'm writing a program where I have a JFrame and I want to remove all components from it, then add just one component to it and repaint the frame. What I have so far is something like the code below (called in an object that implements JFrame, where StartPanel implements JPanel):

```
removeAll();    
startPanel = new StartPanel();
startPanel.setVisible(true);
add(startPanel);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

However, when I run the code it shows an empty window (not the startPanel) and when I minimize/resize the window, the window turns black. If I leave out the `removeAll()` and there are not elements already on the JFrame it displays the startPanel just fine. Any ideas on how to actually remove everything, and then get the new panel to still show up?

Comment: One word: [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that might work, but is there some other way to do it manually? and why isn't removeAll() working as I think it should? what if in other parts of the code I need to have some combinations of different components (not just one showing at a time), so I don't want a CardLayout?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You must call

```
 private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 ...
 ...
 frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
 frame.repaint();
```

`removeAll()` has not been overridden as `add()` or `remove()` to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary.

Comment: @scae: Kavka appears to have the sharper eyes than the rest of us. Good catch and 1+.

Comment: Thank you for your concise and helpful answer. `removeAll()` really should have been overridden like `add()` and `remove()` the way you described. Just another one of Java's odd quirks...

Comment: A call to `revalidate()` may also be necessary just as shown in the original question, but not in this answer. Calling `revalidate()` is necessary if you later add something else to the JFrame. I know this isn't the original question, but I believe it is a common enough use case to note it here. As it was my use case and I found this question/answer in my Google search.

Answer (score 6):

assuming your goal is to add something else after
you clear the frame you should call validate after
adding thoes components to update it

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
add(/*a new component*/);
validate();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
getContentPane().repaint();
```