# How to remove the close button of a JFrame decoration in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

How can I remove the close button of a JFrame in Swing while the min/max buttons and the rest of the frame decoration shall still be available? TYVMIA

Comment: In Java/Swing - you can't ... or not from a "natively generated" window decoration.  You "could" make a look and feel delegate which did the same job, but you quickly lose cross platform conformance.  You could also "roll your own" by making the window undecorated and apply your own "fake" window decoration, but it's much in the same as crafting your own look and feel delegate - some problems and issues

Comment: Is cross-platform compatibility necessary for your project?

Comment: Cross-platform compatibility is important, yes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would you mind copying your above comment as an answer to get the well earned reputation points?

Comment: (BTW you can set Swing to ignore that button: [`setDefaultCloseOperation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java/Swing - you can't ... or not from a "natively generated" window decoration.

You "could" make a look and feel delegate which did the same job, but you quickly lose cross platform conformance.

You could also "roll your own" by making the window undecorated and apply your own "fake" window decoration, but it's much in the same as crafting your own look and feel delegate - same problems and issues

Take a look at [Customizing the Title bar of an Application Window](https://medium.com/swlh/customizing-the-title-bar-of-an-application-window-50a4ac3ed27e) for some "inspiration".

This also suggestions making use of JNI/JNA, which further complicates the issues.

You might also like to have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869877/how-to-remove-window-box-from-any-java-gui/16869893#16869893), it demonstrates how you can move an undecorated window, resizing is simular, but a adds and additional level of complexity.