# Swing application freezes

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am pretty new to the AWT/Swing programming, so I do not see the problem.
When the event is called, the window freezes even before removing the components and I have to close it manually.

So, what's wrong with this code?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    if(((JButton)event.getSource()).getName() == "start")
    {
        for(Component c : QuizShow.frame.getContentPane().getComponents())
        {
            if(c.getName() == "wrapper")
            {
                final JPanel wrapper = (JPanel) c;

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater
                (
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() {
                                wrapper.removeAll();
                                QuizPanel qp = new MainQuizPanel();
                                qp.setup();
                                wrapper.add(qp);
                        }
                    }
                );

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(event.getSource());      
}
```

Edit:
This is the qp.setup() void:

```
public void setup()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            questions[i*6+j] = new JButton();
            questions[i*6+j].setText(""+i*10);;
            add(questions[i*6+j]);
        }
    }   
}
```

This is the main(String[] args) class:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater
    (
        new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                frame = new QuizShowFrame("Quiz Show");
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(100, 100);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }               
        }
    );
```

And the QuizShowFrame class:

```
public class QuizShowFrame extends JFrame
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public QuizPanel introPanel = new Intro();

public JPanel p = new JPanel();

public QuizShowFrame(String name) 
{
    super(name);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Container c = this.getContentPane();

    p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    p.setName("wrapper");
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    c.add(p);

    p.add(introPanel);

    try
    {
        introPanel.setup();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And finally in the Intro class:

```
public void setup()
{
    //...skipped JTextPanes...

    JButton gameStart = new JButton("Start the quiz show");
    gameStart.setName("start");

    try {
        gameStart.addActionListener(Listener.class.newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    add(gameStart);
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of never ending recursion going on here?

Comment: have you done some debugging by stepping  into the code?

Comment: Side problem, don't do this: `if(c.getName() == "wrapper")`. Use equals or equalsIgnoreCase. As for your main problem, you're stomping on the Swing event thread somewhere, where -- hard to say based on the code snippet posted. Create and post your [mcve]. Note that this is not a full code dump -- read the link.

Comment: In `actionPerformed()`, you are already running on the EDT.  All Swing events are invoked on the EDT.  So there's no need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.  Just do all of that right on the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getName().equals("start"))
    {
        for(final Component c : QuizShow.frame.getContentPane().getComponents())
        {
            if(c.getName().equals("wrapper"))
            {
                ((JPanel) c).removeAll();
                c.repaint();
                QuizPanel qp = new MainQuizPanel();
                ((JPanel) c).add(qp);
                qp.setup();
                c.validate();

                break;
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

[This  helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347076/how-to-remove-all-components-from-a-jframe-in-java)
It seems the .validate() solved it.